# What is a good textbook that teaches three dimensional geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, 3d

I am looking for a textbook that thoroughly and clearly teaches three dimensional geometry for a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: In the hope it's useful, [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Mathematics_%28Bookshelf%29) has the public-domain (1919) book [_Solid Geometry with Problems and Applications_](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29807) by Slaught and Lennes.